# What is Takumi's position in the Walker Family?

Tags: maid-sama

After some time, it is discovered that Takumi Usui is member of the Walker Family. The family connection, however, is unclear.

What's the Takumi's position in the Walker Family? How can he become the Walker Family heir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usui is the son of a woman from the Walker Family, Patricia Walker, and her butler, Yuu Hirose. According to maid-sama.wikia.com:

> Usui's family has started to worry as Gerard is supposed to be the next inheritor of their wealth. So they began to search for Usui to put him under their control (they asked him to transfer to Miyabigaoka) so that they would have another inheritor in case something happens to Gerard.

Comment: As far as I know, Takumi is an illegitimate child.